# Wackerly (2007) vs. Larsen (2018) — Introduction to Mathematical Statistics

Tags: textbooks

1. How does [Dennis Wackerly, Richard L. Scheaffer's *Mathematical Statistics with Applications*, 7th Edition  published in 2007](https://www.cengage.com/mathematical-statistics-with-applications-44-7th-edition-7e-wackerly-mendenhall-scheaffer/9780495110811/) MATERIALLY differ from [Richard J. Larsen, Morris Marx's *Introduction to Mathematical Statistics and Its Applications*, 6th Edition published in 2018](https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/program/Larsen-Introduction-to-Mathematical-Statistics-and-Its-Applications-An-6th-Edition/PGM276291.html)? [Wackerly died in 2019](https://www.legacy.com/us/obituaries/gainesville/name/dennis-wackerly-obituary?pid=192704250).
2. Does the 11 year difference matter?

I riffled them at the library. They both offer a Student's Solution Manual to half the exercises, and a password protected Instructor Solutions Manual to all exercises. But I PREFER students to be able to freely access all solutions to all exercises!<sup>1</sup>

I loathe they're both grayscale! It's blindingly — pun intended — obvious that color can ameliorate graphs and charts! See below.

[image]
[image]

<sup>1</sup>In the [Preface](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Er-ash/RV/RVPreface.pdf) to [*Real Variables with Basic Metric Space Topology*](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Er-ash/RV.html), Robert  Ash (1935-2015) touts

> I rely especially on one of the most useful of all learning devices: the inclusion of detailed solutions to exercises. Solutions to problems are commonplace in ele-mentary texts but quite rare (although equally valuable) at the upper division undergraduate and graduate level. This feature makes the
> book suitable for independent study, and further widens the audience.

Answer (score 1):

I used the Wackerly text in the typical two-semester math stats course that I taught for many years. Mendenhall was the original author.

I have not used the Larsen text.

The main reason I chose the Wackerly text is because of its nice treatment of linear models using matrices. See section 11.10 Fitting the Linear Model by Using Matrices, and section 13.13 Analysis of Variance Using Linear Models. And it is accessible even though we do not have a linear algebra prerequisite. Larsen does not appear to have anything similar.

I have no problem with grayscale only, especially in an upper level statistics course. And in my opinion the 11-year difference does not matter.

And in my experience students can find every instructor manual on the internet, whether or not it is password protected.

Comment: Thanks. I found the instructor solution manual ("ISM") for Wackerly online, but NOT the ISM for the 6 edn of Larsen. Did you find the latter?